# Is there a clean way to access AppData from a dotnet core application running under WSL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a dotnet core console application which is intended to run from both windows (powershell/DOS) and WSL shells on the same machine.  I would like the application to share settings regardless of environment.

Under Windows, the application area can easily be found using

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).`

However, when running under WSL, this call returns an empty path.

The "best" approach I've been able to come up with under WSL is to use something like...

```
var user = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOGNAME");
var appdatalocal = $"/mnt/c/users/{user}/AppData/Local"
```

which is a lot more brittle than I'm really comfortable with. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should probably call `wslpath` and `wslvar`, https://superuser.com/questions/1271205/how-to-get-the-host-user-home-directory-in-wsl-bash I do not think that there is a binding for it to .NET Core, but you can look around.

Comment: Thanks @fredrik that's a very useful link and looks like a reasonable fallback if I can't get something working directly in the application.    wslpath "$(wslvar LOCALAPPDATA)" appears to return the desired path.